# ui-select: how to set the search string programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

How can I set the search string (i.e., `$select.search`) from my code? Of course the filter on choices should be applied according to the new search string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the ui-select controller using the ng-init directive on your ui-select element:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ui-select ng-init="$parent.myUiSelect = $select" ...>
    ...
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

And then in your controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myUiSelect.search = "new value";
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

HTML:

```
<ui-select id="mySelect">
```

JS:

```
angular.element('#mySelect').controller('uiSelect').search = "<new-search-string>";
```